# Automatically Play audio while showing SwiftUI screen

Tags: ios, swiftui, avaudioplayer, swift5

I would like to show incoming screen like as below. While showing this screen, i wanted to play ring file (mp3). I have added  `Sound.playSounds(soundfile: "ringing.mp3")` line just before window object. But the mp3 file is not playing but the function playsounds is executing.

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        Sound.playSounds(soundfile: "ringing.mp3")

        let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first
        let contentView = IncomingCallView(viewNavigator: ViewNavigator())
        window?.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView:contentView )
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

The sound file is looking like below

```
import AVFoundation

class Sound {

    static var player:AVAudioPlayer?

    static func playaudio(soundfile: String) {

        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: soundfile, ofType: nil){
            print("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<PATH >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>",path)
            do{

                player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
                player?.prepareToPlay()
                player?.play()

            }catch {
                print("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Error >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Use on appear method

```
SomeView()
    .onAppear{ Sound.playAudio }
```

Comment: Thanks. But it is not working for me. I am using swiftui to create screens. From the swift (NSobject) class when the incoming call comes, i have to show the swiftui class with ringing audio. i am showing the incoming call screen like 
        window?.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView:contentView )
Here the audio is not playing. But i tried to play this audio in button action of some other view, it is ringing. But the audio is not playing only in IncomingCallView screen.

Comment: Audio is playing but the sound is too low. i tried setting volume as well. but no luck. Any one has any idea about it,